# Lock axial movement on key joint

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

I have a motor which its output shaft has a key, and it will be connected to a wheel/tyre. I'm wondering how can I lock the hub axially, so there is no way it can move freely along the axis, which could mean that eventually the wheel-tyre could go off. I'm not sure if a split coupling with a keyway a could work, but I doubt it's designed to press the key and restrict axial movement. Any ideas/suggestions, thanks :)

Comment: Are there provisions for a set screw with the key? A shoulder on one face and a retaining ring opposite can work.

Comment: I think it's not meant to be used with a set screw. [this](https://www.dunkermotoren.com/uploads/tx_products/downloads/MKS/plg-52-8885103023.pdf) is the motor/gearbox in question. I'm sorry, I'm not an English native, so I'm not familiar with the English terms in ME. By shoulder, do you mean a geometric restriction to movement? If so, I'll probably go that route, along with a retaining ring.

Comment: If your wheel has a hub where you can fit a threaded hole, a set screw can be used. If you have access to Machinery's Handbook it has all the dimension information you need.

Your interpretation of shoulder is correct, kudos.

Comment: Use a taper-lock system - often found on pulleys.

Comment: @jko It will be a custom hub, so I could include that. So, the set screw will be tightened against the face of the key, is that what you mean?

Comment: @pollitoalabrasa yes

Answer (score 1):

In modern automobiles, this age-old problem has been solved by using flanged coupling between wheel and driveshaft (This also facilitates easy Stepney replacement).

The [reduction box](https://www.dunkermotoren.com/uploads/tx_products/downloads/MKS/plg-52-8885103023.pdf) in your comment led me to do some google searches. I found this
[image] 
This is split-half coupling a standard component in boats. Since it doesn't come very cheap I would suggest to make CAD to your required dimensions 3D print it and then use grub/set screws instead of a key.

Do let me know if there are any issues